# PostgreSQL live and test database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm working with PostgreSQL now for a few months. Now before going live we usually used the live database for almost everything (creating new columns in the live database tables, executing update and insert queries etc.). But now we want to go live and we have to do things differently before we do that. The best way is to have a test database and live database.

Now I created a copy of the live database so we have a test database to run tests on. The problem is that the data is old after 24 hours, so we actually need to create a fresh copy every 24 hours, which is not really smart to do manually.

So my question is, are there people over here who know a proper way to handle this issue?

I think the most ideal way is:
- copy a selection of tables from the live database to the test database (skip tables like users).
- make it possible to add columns, rename them or even delete them and when we deploy a new version of the website, transfer those changes from the test database to the live database (net necassary but would be a good feature).

Comment: Restore the test system once per day, in the middle of the night, using the backup/restore functionality that you have surely implemented for the live system.

Comment: I just answered a very similar question over on dba.SE; see http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/77711/7788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database structure is changing, you do **NOT** want it automatic.  You *will* blow away dev work and data.  You want it manual.

---

I once managed a team that had a situation similar: multi-TiB database, updated daily, and needing to do testing and development against that up-to-date data.  Here was the way we solved it:

In our database, we defined a function called `TODAY()`.  In our live system, this was a wrapper for `NOW()`.  In our test system, it called out to a one-column table whose only row was a date that we could set.  This means that our test system was a time machine, that could pretend any date was the current one.

This meant that every function or procedure we wrote had to be time-aware.  Should I care about future-scheduled events?  How far in the future?  This made our functions extremely robust, and made it dead simple to test them against a huge variety of historical data.  This helped catch a large number of bugs that we would have never thought would happen, but we saw would indeed occur in our historical data.  It's like functional programming for your database!

We would still schedule database updates from a live backup, about every month or so.  This had the benefit of more data AND testing our backup/restore procedure.  Our DBA would run a "post-test-sync" script that would set permissions for developers, so we were damn sure than anything we ran on the test system would work on the live one as well.  This is what helped us build our deployment database scripts.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. So you where writing scripts which uses TODAY() instead of NOW(). In your live database TODAY() was just a wrapper for NOW() and in your test database the TODAY() function was just another date? And you where able to set a date range as well? It does sound as a great solution